# Get actual data from ext.data.store

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I have this data store

```
 mystore= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: _id.boxesComboStore,
        fields: ['label', 'value', 'id', 'type'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'url/to/controller',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'MyModel'
            }
        }
})
```

How can I easily access the actual data in the store? For example the third record, actual value of type if I have more than one record in the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the third record, one way to get the data is by using [`getAt(id)`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getAt):

```
var store = Ext.getStore('StoreId');
var record = store.getAt(2).data
var type = record.type;
```

In order for [`Ext.getStore(name)`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getStore) to work, you must define a `storeId` for your store.